# From the given data, find the inverse of the matrix $M(x)$

Tags: matrices

> If $A$ is a 3 by 3 matrix and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $M(x)$ is the matrix defined as $M(x)=I+xABB^{T}$ and $k$ is the element the single ton matrix $B^TAB$. Prove that the inverse of $M(x)$ is $M(\frac{-x}{1+kx})$

For the value to be proven, I first found matrix $M(x)M(y)$ which is 
$$M(x)M(y)=M(x+y+kxy)$$

If $$M(x)M(y)=M(x+y+kxy)=O$$

Then $$y=\frac{-x}{1+kx}$$

I feel this is somehow related to the problem, but this just about what I was able to figure out. I do think $M(x)M(y)=O$, but I have no way of proving it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the inverse of $M(x)$ is $M(y)$ for some scalar $y$. Then
\begin{align*}
M(x)M(y) & = I\\
M(x+y+kxy)&=I\\
(x+y+kxy)ABB^T &=0\\
(x+y+kxy)\underbrace{\color{red}{B^T}AB}_{k}B^T &=\color{red}{B^T}0\\
(x+y+kxy)kB^T&=0
\end{align*}
But $B^T$ is not a zero matrix. This means the scalar $(x+y+kxy)k=0$. Since $k=B^TAB$, so unless sum of all the entries of $A$ are zero (which is possible), we can assume that $k \neq 0$. In this latter scenario, we have 
$$x+y+kxy=0 \implies y=\frac{-x}{1+kx}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I think you can verify the statement directly. We have that:
$$ M(x) M(\frac{-x}{1+kx}) = (I + xABB^t)(I - \frac{x}{1+kx} ABB^t) $$
and thois is equal to:
$$ I + xABB^t - \frac{x}{1+kx} ABB^t - \frac{x^2}{1+kx} ABB^t ABB^t $$
and remember that by definition $k = B^t AB$, so substitute this in the last summand to get:
$$ I + xABB^t - - \frac{x}{1+kx} ABB^t - \frac{x^2k}{1+kx} ABB^t $$
which yields the thesis.

Comment: can you write an answer that does not reverse the proof, because I was not supposed to know the answer beforehand (it was an MCQ). I don't want to verify it

Comment: @Aditya Yes, but in this case it is a natural ansatz (guess) to make. When you realize your first equation is correct, and that $M(0)=I$, then it is natural to try $y$ st the argument is 0.

Comment: @Bcpicao but $M(0)=I$ is not obvious

Comment: @Aditya, I don't understand, wasn't $M(x)$ defined to be $I + xABB^T$? Anyway without knowing the answer beforehand to me it isn't even obvious that the inverse of $M(x)$ is of the form $M(y)$ for some $y$, so I'll think about a different solution in a minute.

Comment: Sorry, it is obvious. Your solution is correct. I just didn't realise what he was talking about, but $M(0)=I$ is obvious.